# what is the purpose of db=0 when connecting to redis server in python?

Tags: python, redis

In the redis python client documentation most examples have db=0 passed in constructor parameters. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis

What is the use of db=0 and in what case should i use other values instead of 0?

```
import redis

redis_client = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are 16 databases that a redis server starts up with. They are labeled 0-15. If you chose to and organized your data accordingly, you could manipulate data in each of these. When connecting, you need to choose one. The default choice is `db=0`.  However, it could have been any number in the range 0-15.

Comment: Couldn't find documentation on REDIS about it, but it's probably right in my face and can't see it. If anything stumble upon it, please share a link with me. I'll go on looking in the meantime. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple databases in redis. In redis, databases are identified using integers rather than name. So here, 'db' is database number to which you want to connect.